# JavaScript - Trying to add a prototype from within a prototype

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype, subclass

This sounds easier than it should be, but I'm having issues trying to resolve this. My situation is basically, I can create a class that's going to use prototype (example: `function exClass() {}`).

And if I want to add onto the class, I can just use: `exClass.prototype.newMethod() = '';`.

So why is it that if I'm in, for example, the prototype "newMethod", I can't add a new prototype to "exClass" anymore. An example of what I mean is: `this.prototype.test_var1 = ''` - it fails, as does `exClass.test_var1`.

Why am I unable to add more to the class from within one of its subclasses?

Answer (score 4):

The prototype of an object is *not* a property called `prototype` on the object. The prototype field on a function is the object that will become the prototype of objects created with that function. An object can access the prototype of the function that created it through the `constructor` function. For example, `this.constructor.prototype.test_var1 = ''` would work in most cases.

I say in most cases because many JavaScript engines have a built in `__proto__` that is the object's prototype and can be modified on the fly, but this is not supported in IE for example.

In ES5 you can use Object.getPrototypeOf() to get the prototype reliably. So for example, you can say, `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).test_var1 = ''` in ES5 which will work in modern browsers but not browsers without ES5 support.

Answer (score 3):

The `prototype` property of the constructor function `exClass` does not refer to the same object as the `prototype` property of an *instance* of `exClass`, which is what `this` references inside `newMethod`. Proof:

```
function exClass() {}
exClass.prototype.newMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.prototype === exClass.prototype); // false
    console.log(this.prototype); // undefined
}

var obj = new exClass();
obj.newMethod();
```

Output:

```
false
undefined
```

More generally, every object in JavaScript has a prototype *object*. The `prototype` *property* of a function specifies what the prototype *object* will be for the class of objects created with that function.

Nothing prevents you from modifying a function's `prototype` from within another function:

```
exClass.prototype.newMethod = function() {
    exClass.prototype.anotherMethod = function() {}
}
```

Or more generically:

```
exClass.prototype.newMethod = function() {
    this.constructor.anotherMethod = function() {}
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get at an object's parent prototype via `this.prototype`. You have to use `this.constructor.prototype` (although this will affect the behavior of all objects of that type, in this case `exClass`).  This snippet will alert 'hello world'.

```
function exClass() {};

exClass.prototype.newMethod = function() {
    this.constructor.prototype.test_var1 = 'hello world';
}

obj = new exClass();
obj.newMethod();
alert(obj.test_var1);
```